# Please add thousand separators in the tag counts when tagging a question

Tags: feature-request, tags

Pretty much everything with possibly-high counts (rep, question views) is nicely formatted with thousands separators, but the counts displayed when adding tags aren't.

[image]

Comment: Exact number usually doesn't matter, something like reputation format will looks better in this window (e.g. your rep is displayed as `17.5k` currently): for `C#` it would be `1.3M`. Good/bad ? Tooltip can show exact number and yes: with thousand separators pleases.

Comment: I vote for European thousands seperators, not those silly US ones

Comment: a typical "it happened to be a problem first on SO" problem :)

Comment: +1_000_000! Underscores are the region-neutral programming-friendly thousands separator, let's go with those!

Comment: @Jeremy: Disagreement from the C++ crowd, which uses single-quote: `1'000'000`.

Comment: How about we choose something we can all agree on?  as a delimiter.

Comment: For the 1000000000th time, what we need are cat separators.

Comment: @billynoah or a "pick your own emoji" separator in user preferences?

Comment: @Tschallacka I'm not sure if you're joking but as an Australian I would be extremely horrified if they used full stops for separating thousands. I didn't even know Europeans did it backwards until about 2 years ago. It's so weird. 1.37 in English is "one-point-three-seven". 1,37 naturally reads (to me, at least) like "one-comma-thirty-seven", which is nonsensical. Commas also naturally look like pauses when reading large numbers. Do you feel the same way about the AU/GB/US (there's probably other countries that use it) system (full stops for decimal points, commas for thousands separators)?

Comment: @Clonkex Of course I was joking. I hate the European style with a passion. Everytime I work with Excel or some other localized program I am frustrated beyond words to have to type a comma, or replace all dots with comma's to get stuff working or numbers recognized. And turning to dots is a pain because there is some deeply buried windows setting to change for that, not in the program itself.

Comment: @Clonkex If you think about it, "one-point-three-seven" is just as nonsensical as "one-comma-three-seven". The only difference is that you are used to the one and not the other. Commas are easier to write (I'm talking about pen and paper here) than dots, and dots are easier to type (if you use the right-hand side numeric keys) than commas. There really is no other difference.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yep. I'm not saying "one-point-three-seven" inherently makes sense, I'm just saying the way we speak it out loud in English means a comma makes no sense. I would also disagree that commas are easier to write. Personally I find them virtually identical in terms of ease of writing.

Comment: @Tschallacka Good, we agree. I also have a strong aversion to the European style. However I'm not sure why you say "of course I was joking" as if it's obvious. It's not obvious. In fact I'm a bit surprised. Your location is listed as Kleef, Duitsland so it's reasonable for me to assume you're probably European. Sarcasm doesn't come across well in text, so your original comment could be taken either way.

Answer (score 61):

In agreement with @Sinatr, I feel that the exact number of questions tagged with a particular tag is not meaningful, only the order of magnitude is. It's probably wrong all the time due to caching anyway.

As a result, I would follow their suggestion: simply use the abbreviation already used for scores: `17.5k`, `725k`, `1.3M`, ...

It could also benefit from the rounding that "short scores" get, as well.

Comment: Am I the only one who considers `1,234,567` more readable (to *feel* the number), than `1.23M`?

Comment: @VisioN: No you're not the only one...

Comment: @VisioN `1,234,567` > `1.23m` > `1234567`

Comment: @VisioN From a UX perspective, displaying _multiple_ large numbers can quickly lead to people simply glazing over and not paying attention to _any_ of the numbers, similar to a wall of text, or a paragraph with every other word bolded. In this case, where we want the author to be focusing more on the name of the tag, and then using the popularity of the tag to get a feel for if it's the correct tag, it makes a bit more sense to have less emphasis on the numbers. Right now the C# tag currently has more display space allocated to the number of posts, than the tag name itself.

Comment: @VisioN: Please propose this as an answer, so it is more visible, and can compete with mine. Thinking on it, I also think that `1,234,567` is also more *universal*, stack exchange sites other than programming/engineering may find it more human friendly.

Comment: @VisioN Do you prefer 1.23e6 ?

Comment: @Stargateur Better `0x12d687`, but we can shorten it to `12d687`.

Comment: Better binary with spaces every 4 bits.

Comment: And PLEASE, do NOT use "m" for million. Use "M" as in mega instead.

Comment: @VisioN You are the only one

Answer (score 13):

<sup>Following [suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382479/please-add-thousand-separators-in-the-tag-counts-when-tagging-a-question?cb=1#comment685422_382497) from Matthieu, I'm posting my thoughts below.</sup>

I think keeping properly formatted numbers (e.g. `1,234,567`) makes more sense than introducing short equivalents (like `1.23M`), especially in places where we don't need to win much screen space.

`1,234,567` format is good from many perspectives, where the main is **readability**. I am coming not only from the *visual feeling* of a number, but also from the fact that it may potentially be more user friendly for non-technical people (I consider this change for SE platform, rather than for SO only).

As an example, quite often my eyes don't get the difference between `123` and `123k` in user's reputation, while subconsciously I can clearly see the difference between `123` and `123,456`.

Regarding the formatting (separators, grouping, etc), I'd vote for browser locale and/or user preferences.

Comment: Why would non-technical people find it more readable to display higher precision in numbers? If anything, it seems order of magnitude displays would be better for non-technical folks. (And everyone else, in this case, for the reasons Matthieu points out.)

Comment: @CodyGray: I wonder if non-technical people could get confused with the abbreviations. In programming, we are used to kB, MB, etc... however outside you rarely see prices mentioned as $12k for a car, it's more likely spelled out as $12,000.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I don't think "non-technical people" are *illiterate*. I struggle to think who would be confused for very long if they see "113k", like, for example, the repotation count of VisioN here. Or if somebody truly finds the concept impossible to grasp, would they even be visiting Stack Exchange? Also, I've seen a lot of people talk about money in the form of $12k. It's not usually official (as in, in an ad or job listing) but it seems fairly common for people to discuss sums of money in "k" or even "mil". Even "non-technical" people.

Comment: @MatthieuM. "In programming, we are used to kB, MB, etc.." where we should use ko, Mo, etc... ^^

Comment: Stack Overflow is intended to be a site by experts for experts in the field of programming. We can very safely assume that people who don't understand "1.23M" are not targeted by this site. If you're also talking about other SE-sites you may have a point, but I still believe that the problem with people not understanding those prefixes are very minor. And being able to choose this on user level has very little value compared to the cost of writing the code and maintaining it.

Comment: @MatthieuM. You don't see prices like $12k in an ad, but it is fairly common to write like that when chatting casually.

Comment: There's a reason the `--human-readable` argument for the `df` and `du` commands in unices changes numerical outputs to "27G", "484M", etc. Also, often the reason you don't see $12k in an advertisement is because advertisers insist on using silly tricks like writing $11,950 to try and make you forget you're spending almost 12 grand on something.

Comment: @Broman According to our tour page: *Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional **and enthusiast** programmers.* (emphasis mine). I think that leaves room for non-experts, and if it doesn't, we definitely need to redirect people who click the *I need help with a homework problem* option in the ask question wizard.

Comment: @Broman: I was seeing this as a potentially more general (whole Stack Exchange) improvement; if specific to Stack Overflow I would hope that everyone groks the use of k/M/G indeed.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl True, but I still think it's reasonable to expect people to understand "1.23M"

Comment: @Broman I agree with Matthieu here. I was also considering that mostly as a Stack Exchange improvement, as to me it doesn't make sense applying this logic to technical platforms only. And yes, the vast majority of people should understand magnitude displays, however my accent was mainly about general readability, e.g. quite often my eyes don't get the difference between `123` and `123k` in user's reputation, when subconsciously I can clearly see the difference between `123` and `123,456`.

Comment: @VisioN I have to admit that you have a valid point there

Comment: @Broman I've updated my answer to send my message more clear.

Comment: @Broman I agree, just wanted to point out that we're not all experts here.

Comment: "123 k" is the proper way to spell it (according to the SI standard), not "123k". I think the added space makes it more readable. And "k", "M", "G" prefixes are not limited to computer people at all, even though computer speak have made them even more widely-known (people choose internet speeds in Mb or Gb, computers with GB and TB memory, etc.)